# What kind of table to use for tags system?

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I want to implement a tagging system on a website I'm working on.
I have a theoretical question about this. How would I store those tags in my database?

If for example I use a table with two columns, tags and postId I could have a certain tag an incredible amount of times if it is popular! So I'm not sure if this is the best way.

If I want to add tags to posts, and I have 3 posts with the tag 'cool' I'd have something like this:

```
tag-----id
cool----23
cool----12
cool----39
```

Are there better ways to achieve this?

Comment: duplicate of [Database Design for Tagging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475/database-design-for-tagging) and [Designing tag system that can tag multiple db tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360629/designing-tag-system-that-can-tag-multiple-db-tables). Please do not ignore [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a post table, a tags table and a join table:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (id, title, body)
CREATE TABLE tags (id, tag)
CREATE TABLE posts_tags (tag_id, post_id)
```

This is fine. Make sure you add indexes on the tag, tag_id and post_id columns.

Comment: prexactly - this is how you do any N:N relationship